# Se puede configurar el tamaño de la consola mediante C++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

estaba buscando un modo para predeterminar el tamaño de la ventana de la consola en mi programa, pero lo poco que he encontrado es en C y no me ha funcionado. Alguien sabe de alguna forma para hacerlo? O por qué me falla al intentarlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que he probado para configurar el tamaño:

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SMALL_RECT windowSize = { 0, 0, 40, 50 };
SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, 1, &windowSize);
```

PD: También he probado con esto, pero tampoco me funciona (ambos cambian el máximo de espacios donde aparece el texto, pero no reforman la consola al tamaño):

```
system("mode con cols=40 lines=50");
```

Answer (score 0):

Como menciona [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36983796/13419694), el nombre de la función [`SetConsoleWindowInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) es engañoso. Ya que lo que permite es posicionar y cambiar el tamaño del buffer de la consola, no de la ventana.

En su lugar, deberías usar la función [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos). Por ejemplo:

```
HWND window = GetConsoleWindow();
SetWindowPos(window, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, nuevoAncho, nuevoAlto, SWP_NOMOVE);
```

El segundo parámetro te permite establecer el orden y los 4 siguientes la posición, y tamaño de la ventana. El último parámetro permite entre otras cosas, mantener el orden, la posición y/o el tamaño.

Comment: he probado ese comando, pero sigue sin funcionarme también. La ventana no reacciona, no se me reajustan los textos, no cambia de tamaño la ventana, etc. Puede ser que tenga que ver la versión en la que trabajo? Estoy en C++20.

Comment: @Kuko C++20 es el estándar de C++ y eso solo afecta las características del lenguaje y la librería estándar. Esto es de Windows y no tiene nada que ver. A lo mejor no te funciona porque estás con la terminal nueva.